# radio buttons in a tableview cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Currently I am trying to make a store-like view that shows multiple different listing (spaceships) and you can only select one at a time. It would be for a game where you can select your different spaceships. I am sing a UITableView with a UITableViewCell Xib file. I have only one table cell Xib file to format all of the different listings. The style of the Select button is suppose to be like a Radio Button.

The difficulty I am having is that when I click one button, it makes all the buttons say "Selected."

This is the code that I have:

TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

struct CellData {
    var image: UIImage?
    var message: String?
    var id: Int?

}

var array = [String]()
var buttonArray = [ShopButton]()


class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data = [CellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        data = [CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ship_0"), message: "Red Ship", id: 0), CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ship_1"), message: "Blue Ship", id: 1), CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ship_3"), message: "Yellow Ship", id: 2)]
        array = ["Select", "Select", "Select"]

            }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell
        cell.mainImageView.image = data[indexPath.row].image
        cell.mainLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].message
        cell.buttonOutlet.setTitle(array[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        cell.buttonOutlet.tag = data[indexPath.row].id!
        buttonArray.append(cell.buttonOutlet)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }



}
```

TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: ShopButton!



    @IBAction func button(_ sender: ShopButton) {
        buttonOutlet.makeSelected()
    }



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


    }
```

My SubClass for the UIButton:

```
import UIKit

class ShopButton: UIButton {

    var buttonID = Int()

    func makeSelected() {

            switch self.buttonID {
            case 0:
                array = ["Selected", "Select", "Select"]
                buttonTitle()
                print("Ship: Red Ship")
            case 1:
                array = ["Select", "Selected", "Select"]
                buttonTitle()
                print("Ship: Blue Ship")
            case 2:
                array = ["Select", "Select", "Selected"]
                buttonTitle()
                print("Ship: Yellow Ship")
            default:
                print("Error: Default Initiated")
            }

    }
    func buttonTitle() {

        for button:ShopButton in buttonArray {
            button.setTitle(array[button.buttonID], for: .normal)
        }

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    }

}
```

I realize this might not be the best approach to making this shop setup so if anyone has an answer to how to fix this or a different way that would be much better than what I have currently done, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far. Also mention your problem properly, like do you need radio button implementation in each cell separately or your table view cell will work as an option

Comment: This answer gives code-free radio buttons in a `UITableView` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52401326/123632

Answer (score -1):

You can possibly use this logic in `didSelectRowAt` in table view like:

You can make the tag of button equivalent to the `indexpath.row` of `tableview`

```
        for (button in buttons)    {
             button.isSelected = false;   
        }

        if button.tag == indexpath.row{ //Here sender.tag would be your indexPath.row
            button.isSelected = true;
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_Radio_filled"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            button.isSelected = false;
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_Radio_Empty"), for: .normal)
        }
```

Let me know if it works for you.