# Swift tableview cell radio button implementation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to place a radio button in tableview custom cell. whenever user clicks the tableview cell or button then radio button needs to work. I tried by using below code but didn't execute well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TableViewCell

        cell.country.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;

        if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
        {
            cell.radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What didn't work? What happened? What did you expect to happened? What happens when you put breakpoints n the code? Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a great solution for creating radio buttons in a `UITableView` using a storyboard that requires *zero* code - and has 2 great ***Cool Tips!!***

- Make sure your table view is set to **Single Selection**, and to use **Static cells**.
- Add a **Basic** cell, set the image to be your unchecked button image, and make sure the selection style is **Default**

[image]

- ***Cool Tip # 1:*** Click on and select the cell's image view, and then set it's **highlighted image** to be your checked state. When the cell is highlighted or selected, the image view within will change to show its highlighted state.

[image]

- ***Cool Tip # 2:*** Next, drag a `UIView` into the cell's content view, behind the text label. As you're using a basic cell, you won't be able to drop it directly into the cell, you'll need to drag it into onto the Document Outline on the left instead. Then hook this up to the cell's **selected background view** outlet. When a cell is selected (or highlighted), this view will be displayed in the background. In this case, we're going to use it to prevent the grey background appearing, so set its colour to **Clear**. Note that it doesn't matter what size the view is, and there's no need to set any constraints - it's automatically sized to match the cell at runtime.

[image]

- Finally, duplicate this cell and change the text for each of your radio button options. Build and run, and you have code-free radio buttons!

[image]

Comment: Great. I will try and update you here. Thank you lot! @Ashley Mills

Answer (score 1):

In your `TableViewCell` class why don't you create a data source element and override the `didSet` for it. also in your data source for the `UITableView` I would recommend an array of something more than just a `String`.

I haven't compiled the below so this is just an idea.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    var data: Animal? {
        didSet {
            self.country.text = data.description
            if (data.isSelected) {
                self.radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                self.radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your view controller you will of course have to set the `isSelected` property whenever a row is tapped.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var animal = self.animals[indexPath.row]
    animal.isSelected = !animal.isSelected
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TableViewCell

    cell.data = self.animals[indexPath.row]
}
```

and for your `Animal` maybe something like this:

```
struct Animal {
    var description: String
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

Comment: You get an upvote for setting a property on the cell rather than updating its outlets directly.

Comment: I will try and update you here @Dennis White Thank you so much